# Appropriate preposition to go with "concerned"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> He is deeply concerned for vulnerable children.

Is this correct? Or is there a better preposition to use instead of *for*? What exactly does this phrase mean?

What about "He is deeply concerned with vulnerable children"?

Comment: Concerned is usually followed by "about" although "with" and "on" are also grammatically correct (and "in" with a different meaning). Regarding "for" I'm not sure but you can check the usage diagram at http://goo.gl/3qHfP...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a few variation to be used with *to be concerned*.

One can be concerned with something. This would have a meaning similar of [*to deal with*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deal#Etymology_2)

> I am concerned with daily maintenance of our machines.

One can be concerned about something/someone. This would be the preposition which could be use in your case, but it would give it a meaning of [*caring about*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/care#Etymology_2).

> He is deeply concerned about vulnerable children

Of course, *for* seems to be used, although I rarely heard it (which is in no way an indication of the frequency it could be found), [it is used](http://www.searchquotes.com/quotation/If_God_had_wanted_us_to_be_concerned_for_the_plight_of_the_toads,_he_would_have_made_them_cute_and_f/47678/).

**EDIT:** See [Dan Ray's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41587/appropriate-preposition-to-go-with-concerned/41633#41633) for a use with the *for* preposition.

Answer (score 1):

*To have a concern for* something means there is something your attention is on, something you're committed to. I have a concern for my boss's satisfaction with my performance, the amount of time I spend on Stack Exchange sites notwithstanding.

Comment: But is 'He is concerned for vulnerable children' acceptable? Is it commonly used?

Answer (score 0):

'Concerned for' is certainly idiomatic, but has a different meaning from 'show concern for/have a concern for', which means 'have a deep interest in / compassion for'. Like 'concerned about', it means 'worried about':

> **concerned** [adjective] {worried} [+ *about*, less commonly *for*]
>
> - *I'm a bit concerned about/for your health.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary; modified slightly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concerned)]

> - *Her family was very concerned for her safety*.

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerned)]

So 'concerned for' is acceptable here, but primarily indicates worry rather than compassion. 'Have a concern for' can equally indicate worry **and/or** compassion, so it works, but is ambiguous.

....................

'Concerned with' means something different, 'involved with':

> **concerned with** something: interested in something / dealing with something
>
> - *The public is increasingly concerned with how food is produced*. [here, the 'worry' sense informs]
> - *Mathematics is concerned essentially with understanding abstract concepts.* [no worry hinted at here]

[[Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary; modified slightly](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/concerned)]

So 'deeply concerned with' isn't really idiomatic, and 'He is concerned with vulnerable children' doesn't mean he has a concern for them.